# Java 8 repeatable annotations analog for prior versions

Tags: java, annotations, java-8

If you want to repeat annotation java 8 allow this.

example:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Repeatable(MyAnnotationContainer.class)
@interface MyAnnotation {

    String value();

}

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@interface MyAnnotationContainer {

    MyAnnotation[] value();
}

@MyAnnotation( "a")
@MyAnnotation( "b")
class MyClass {
}
```

In description I have read that it is just hint for java compiler to generate code.

Please clarify how does this code looks in java 5-7 ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Before Java 8, the annotations would need to be wrapped explicitly as in this example:

```
@MyAnnotationContainer({
  @MyAnnotation("a"),
  @MyAnnotation("b")
})
class MyClass {
}
```

This is also the way the annotations are exposed at runtime via the reflection API. Java 8 only added some [syntactic suggar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) for this explicit wrapping as this is a common use case.

Comment: Syntactic sugar and [convenience methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AnnotatedElement.html#getDeclaredAnnotationsByType-java.lang.Class-)…